# ¿Como le sumo minutos a una hora que tengo?

Tags: javascript, date

Tengo un texbox en donde se  muestra la hora actual en formato de 24hrs, de la siguente manera.

```
 var horaactual= moment(new Date()).format('H:mm'); 
 $('#txthora').val(horaactual);
```

Mi objetivo es que se sume la hora actual del primer campo con el numero de un segundo campo, pero no se como indicarle que dicho numero los interprete como minutos, ya que lo requiero para sumarlos. Ejemplo:

txthora: 20:27 - txtnumero: 7. **resultado**: 20:34.

necesito ayuda para expresarlo en js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
    var fecha = new Date();
    var hora = fecha.getHours();
    var minutos = fecha.getMinutes();
    
    if (hora < 10) {hora = "0" + hora};
    if (minutos < 10) {minutos = "0" + minutos};

    var textoHora = `Hora actual: ${hora}:${minutos}`;
    console.log(textoHora);                 
    
    var numberInput = 15;                   //Acá ingresas el numero que va a sumarse con los minutos
    var newMinutes = minutos + numberInput;

    var counter = 0;    
    for(i = 0; i < newMinutes; i++){  
        counter++;
        if(counter == 60) {
           hora++;
           newMinutes -= 60;
           counter = 0;
        }
    }

    if (hora < 10) {hora = "0" + hora};
    if (newMinutes < 10) {newMinutes = "0" + newMinutes};
    
    console.log(`Nueva Hora: ${hora}:${newMinutes}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo con una funcion que te retorne el objeto original y despues solo le das formato

```
function addMinutes(date, minutes) {
    return new Date(date.getTime() + minutes*60000);
}

var horaactual= new Date(); 
var horamod = moment(addMinutes(horaactual,3)).format("H:mm");
```

El codigo original lo encuentras [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197928/how-to-add-30-minutes-to-a-javascript-date-object)